# Custom Button doesn't work in my Custom Object profile

Tags: visualforce, custom-object, custom-button, permissions

I've attached a custom button to my custom object page layout, that redirects the user in a visualforce page, but when I log in, as a particular user, The system redirects me to an error page that shows me the following error:

https://crabbdemo.force.com/MediasetCommunity is under construction

Stay tuned. Please email us if you need to get in touch.

I've ran the following check on the possible issues:
1) Checked the profile settings for this user on this object, and didn't find any restriction.
2) Checked the security settings on the visualforce page, where the button will adress the user, and no obstacle found.

Please, anyone give me a clue, what might be that prevents the user from accessing the page.

Thanks!
Endrit.

Comment: Are you logging in as a Community User or a Standard User. Is the VF page that you are trying to access on a Community or a Force.com Site?

Comment: The licence of the user with whom I'm trying to log in is  
Partner Community.
I have created just a custom Dettail Button, that simply redirects the user to the vf Page, taking the id of the custom object, as a URL Parameter.

Comment: yes, the reason I asked is, the URL's are different on a community. E.g., when you login as the community user, check what the URL of the page is from where you are invoking the custom button. Is it https://crabbdemo.force.com/AB12132313213/ or is there something after force.com and before the record. Usually it should contain the community name. E.g. if the name of your community is comm, then the URL should look like https://crabbdemo.force.com/comm/AB12132313213/. You would need to account for that in your custom button.

Comment: Thank you! The problem was related with that. I appended my community name, so instead of '[SF instance]/apex/Mypage' there should've been: '[SF instance]/myCommunityName/MyPage'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great that it worked. I am also copying the comment as an answer so that it can be marked as a correct answer.

> yes, the reason I asked is, the URL's are different on a community. E.g., when you login as the community user, check what the URL of the page is from where you are invoking the custom button. Is it crabbdemo.force.com/AB12132313213 or is there something after force.com and before the record. Usually it should contain the community name. E.g. if the name of your community is comm, then the URL should look like crabbdemo.force.com/comm/AB12132313213. You would need to account for that in your custom button

Answer (score 0):

For your custom button to work seamlessly inside and outside Communities, you can append "../" in front of your URL.
For Eg. - If the VF page name is --> Dummy_Test_Page, so the code in the custom button which will be used to call this VF page is:

---

> ../apex/Dummy_Test_Page

---

This will work for both Regular users and Community Users.

NOTE: The Custom button can either be a Detail page button or List button and it's Content Source should be URL